# how can I make a horizontal-vertical table in laravel? (cross table) [Edited]

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, laravel-5.8

i've tried so many step to make this table(the second table):

[second table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJz44.jpg)

with this array

```
{
  "Habie": {
    "2019-07-17": [
      {
        "durasi": "0 Jam",
        "status_durasi": "Kurang"
      }
    ],
    "2019-07-07": [
      {
        "durasi": "0 Jam",
        "status_durasi": "Kurang"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Budiman": {
    "2019-07-13": [
      {
        "durasi": "0 Jam",
        "status_durasi": "Kurang"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and with this array date interval for the table header:

```
[
  "2019-07-20",
  "2019-07-19",
  "2019-07-18",
  "2019-07-17",
  "2019-07-16",
  "2019-07-15",
  "2019-07-14",
  "2019-07-13",
  "2019-07-12",
  "2019-07-11",
  "2019-07-10",
  "2019-07-09",
  "2019-07-08",
  "2019-07-07"
]
```

then, in blade i make looping like this:

```
             <tr>
                <th>NAMA</th>
                @foreach ($tanggalInterval as $key => $item)
                    <th>{{$item}}</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>

            <tr>
                @foreach ($kehadiran as $kData=> $data)
                    <td>{{$kData}}</td>
                    @foreach ($data as $kTanggal => $tanggal)
                        @foreach ($tanggal as $kDrsSts => $item)
                            @foreach ($item as $kItem => $drs)
                            {{-- {{dd()}} --}}
                                {{-- <td>{{$item["durasi"]}}</td> --}}
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </tr>
```

Nb: grand total is found from the total length of work(durasi)

but, no one step work :(.

i hope someone can help me :)

thanks :D

---

**EDITED**:

from this database table:

[database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpLNd.png)

to be:

[The table that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJz44.jpg)

Comment: can you post how does your current table look like in your browser  and update your question?

Comment: @GhiffariAssamar, the current table in Edited part below. help me please :)

Comment: @HabieSmart the problem is table  appearance you need to make like the one in the image or the problem in the data itself  ?

Comment: @HussamAdil yes, more precisely, from database, I want to show my data like that photo. Like table's appearance. I hope you are understand what i mean. Help me please :(

Comment: @HabieSmart You can create **two tables**  the first table for  the top part then print the data and second table for below part , check this link](https://ibb.co/CbJNZbS)

Comment: @HussamAdil, oh I'm sorry. Ignore the first table. I forget to remove that table. I just want my table like the second table

Comment: @HabieSmart do you check the link ?

Comment: @HussamAdil, the link? what do you mean? i cant understand what did you said

Comment: @HabieSmart sorry your question is not  clear at least for me

Comment: @HabieSmart sorry your question is not  clear at least for me

Comment: i mean your current table on  blade, what does it looks like  now? rendered results on browser